# htaccess rewrite for different sets of variables

Tags: .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have several different sets of variables that can be alhpa numeric.

If I comment out any two sets the other will work. Only one set will work but need all three to work.

First set is only one level:

domain.com/index.php?var1a=var1a

The second set can be one, two or three levels:

domain.com/index.php?var2a=var2a

domain.com/index.php?var2a=var2a&var2b=var2b

domain.com/index.php?var2a=var2a&var2b=var2b&var2c=var2c

The third set can be one, two or three levels:

domain.com/index.php?var3a=var3a

domain.com/index.php?var3a=var3a&var3b=var3b

domain.com/index.php?var3a=var3a&var3b=var3b&var3c=var3c

htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?var1a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?var1a=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?var2a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?var2a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?var2a=$1&var2b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?var2a=$1&var2b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?var2a=$1&var2b=$2&var2c=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?var2a=$1&var2b=$2&var2c=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?var3a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?var3a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?var3a=$1&var3b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?var3a=$1&var3b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?var3a=$1&var3b=$2&var3c=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?var3a=$1&var3b=$2&var3c=$3 [L]
```

After testing I understand why this won't work but cannot work out how to define the different sets.

Comment: You're defining the same matches in all three sets - how do the actual original URLs differ? The way it's written, it's like you want Apache to magically know if `domain.com/guesswhat` should go to rule 1, 2, or 3. Please give some example URLs to differentiate between how the three rules should be used.

Comment: The first is for affiliate so its:

Comment: ooops....The first is for affiliate so its: domain.com/?affiliate=username. Second is for post domain.com/?c=cat&m=month&t=tile etc and third is similar to second used for hardcoded links using search terms and tags domain.com/?search=true&keyword=word&keyword2=word2. Something like that if I can get the rewrites to work in this manner

Comment: Those are the destination URLs, but what does the user type in that you're trying to rewrite? For example, for the affiliate link, does the user enter `domain.com/bobsmith` and that needs to be translated to `domain.com/index.php?affiliate=bobsmith`? Then for the search is it `domain.com/search/word1/word2` that goes to `domain.com/index.php?search=true&keyword=word1&keyword2=word2`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, above, the search URLs are the easiest to accommodate since they start with a consistent /search, so that rule will go first:

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ index.php?search=true [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?search=true&keyword=$1 [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?search=true&keyword=$1&keyword2=$2 [L, NC]
```

`/?` makes the trailing slash optional so you can match with or without on the same rule.

That leaves affiliate and post links. Assuming post links have a variety of starting terms (categories), unlike "search", we need to distinguish those from usernames. Usernames only have one level, though, so first we can capture any two or three level URLs as post links:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&m=$2 [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&m=$2&t=$3 [L, NC]
```

Finally, for single level URLs to distinguish between categories and usernames, it's probably the case that there are a limited number of known categories that change infrequently while usernames are more numerous and more prone to change. So, you need a lookup method for categories and then default any that don't match to be usernames.

To lookup categories, you need to use a `RewriteMap`. You'll need to look through [the RewriteMap documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewritemap.html) to determine which type will work best for your situation, but it would end up something like this:

```
#Map is declared in virtual host context, not in .htaccess
RewriteMap categorymap txt:/path/to/file/categories.txt

RewriteCond ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$,${categorymap:$1} ^([^,]+),\1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?affiliate=$1
```

I haven't used RewriteMaps myself or RewriteConds of that particular format, so it may need tweaking, but the idea is that the RewriteCond says to match the incoming path against a capture of everything up to the comma (`^([^,]+)`) and then to match the categorymap against that captured pattern (`\1`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's all working now but I couldn't get my head around RewriteMap just yet so I used this line adding /id/ to the url, RewriteRule ^id/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?affiliate=$1 If the client is happy with that I'll leave it otherwise I will study the RewriteMap a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if you have the option of having a consistent first section of the URL, that will always be easier to work with than mapping.

Comment: I understand Rewrite rules now, never really thought about as most jobs are wordpress or magento so didn't have to think. The client is happy with affiliate urls as domain.com/id/username so all good!! Thanks for your help :-)